Is there a general equation for calculating the heat gained from drag?
Not just the amount of energy converted to heat, but specifically, the amount of energy a part would heat up? I am trying to calculate the heat imparted on the fins of a rocket as it passes through the atmosphere, but because the faster the part moves the less time it will make contact with the air.
I tried some back-of-the-napkin math, but I wasn't sure how speed would affect pressure and didn't know how the temperature gradient in the air would factor in.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You don't appear to understand heat. Heat is the transfer of energy due solely to temperature difference. Things don't "contain" heat. They have internal energy which may increase or decrease based on the amount of energy transferred to or from an object by means of heat and work.

While yes, I used heat instead of thermal energy, heat is also 1/3 the characters, and colloquial, they are used interchangeably

@Evelyn21 yes, but our job here is to distinguish between the colloquial and physics use of the term heat and not promote it


Is there a general equation for calculating the heat gained from drag?

No. There are too many variables involved for a general equation. You have to take account of the speed of the rocket, the density of the atmosphere, the temperature of the atmosphere, the shape of the fins, the mass of the fins, the material of the fins, the way in which the fins are attached to the body of the rocket and probably another dozen significant factors as well. Plus if the rocket is travelling at supersonic speeds the flow of air around the fins will be very complex. To get anything like a realistic solution will involve a lot of complex numerical modelling.
(In short, yes, it really is rocket science !)
